# Reference request for logic programming in Mathematica

Tags: reference-request, logic

I'm learning *Mathematica*(v8) to use it to program formal logic. Can anyone recommend a logic-specific tutorial text? A reference list of logic-related functions would also be very appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259/5

Comment: @rm-rf: Yeah, that post is very helpful as far as general programming is concerned--I was just hoping there might be something more logic-specific out there, as I'm not planning to use the language for anything else.=)

Comment: Ok, no problem. I don't know anything, but someone might answer. In future, it is good practice to mention if you've already seen some relevant resource/material and it didn't satisfy your needs (in this case, the above link) :)

Comment: In The Mathematica Journal Vol4 issue 2, R. Maeder implements a Prolog Interpreter in Mathematica. Very interesting. His package is old and doesn't work any more (since Mathematica 6, I think). I don't know if the problem is serious.

Comment: In addition to @andre314’s comment the Roman Maeder's book from 1996 “The Mathematica Programmer II” contains a whole section (about 30 pages) on “Logic Programming”. Both publications are probably closely related. I did not check whether the code from the book is compatible to current Mathematica versions.

Comment: @user7515079 I have this book. The code doesn't work anymore, but, some years ago, I managed to make it work again. There was several minor issues relatively easy to understand anf one main issue that took me a while to understand, but once understood was easy to fix.

Comment: The issue was a duplicate line a of code, that manifestly was not interpreted the same way beetween different Mathematica versions.

Comment: I seem to recall that one of the minor issue was a local function name that became a built-in name in the new Mathematica versions.

Comment: The duplicate line of code is `qeval[ _, initialState ] := no` in the file LOGICPROGRAMMING.M . The solution is simply to remove this line.

Comment: The conflict with built-in names concern in fact 3 functions defined by R. Maeder in his code : `Query`  `Assert`  `Format` . Simply rename these functions in all the files and it will work.

Comment: @user7515079 You may be interested by my 5 last comments that explain how to make R. Maeder code in "The Mathematica Programmer II" work.

Comment: @andre314 Thank you. That's good news. The book and its code was at that time one of my deeper involvements with Mathematica.